# Overriding * in css style

Tags: html, css, input, vertical-alignment, overriding

My css style sheet:

```
 * {vertical-align:top;}  
input.test {vertical-align:middle;}
```

This is an example of my html code:

```
<input class="test" /><input class="test" />
```

So I would like the class test to override *
I have tried:

```
* {vertical-align:top;}
input.test {vertical-align:middle!important;}
```

But it did not work on Firefox and the vertical-align is still on top...
Thank's!

Comment: My 2 cents. The **!important** declaration should have a space right before it. Input.test should be enough to override the first declaration. Maybe giving us more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...but `vertical-align`, unfortunately, isn't a property that applies to `input` elements.

`!important` in this context, is making no difference.
`input.test`, in fact, is already overriding `*`

Why that? It is a *more specific* selector, and **CSS are all about specificity** of selectors.
*i.e.* the rule with the most specific selector, wins.

Hence, to influence that `input` element appearance, you should target the `td` cell containing it and set *that* `vertical-align` value.

Comment: Additional reading about specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: I did it with CSS properties on `td`. Thank's for your explanations!!